# How to run Node.js CLI REPL with history saving disabled?

Tags: node.js, command-line, terminal, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

I like to test JS/ES APIs that I am/became less familiar with in the Node.js REPL, but most times I don't want anything saved to the REPL history file for later reference or study.

Also the Node CLI REPL, unlike most shells, even when you prefix the command with a space it saves it to history.

I checked Node's manual page with `man node` and `node --help`, there's nothing like `--no-save` that most other CLI REPLs have, the only thing close to it is:

```
Environment variables:
     NODE_REPL_HISTORY file
             Path to the file used to store persistent REPL history.  The default path is ~/.node_repl_history, which is overridden by this variable.  Setting the value to an empty string
             ("" or " ") will disable persistent REPL history.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can, before starting node, temporarily set `NODE_REPL_HISTORY` to something else (e.g `/dev/null`), so the Node.js cli repl doesn't default to saving to the default `~/.node_repl_history`:

`export NODE_REPL_HISTORY="/dev/null" && node`

but don't forget to `unset NODE_REPL_HISTORY` after Node exits so that next time you start Node normally `NODE_REPL_HISTORY` defaults to default configs:

`export NODE_REPL_HISTORY="/dev/null" && node && unset NODE_REPL_HISTORY`

if you would like not type that every time, you can set the line above an alias (command) e.g `nonode`, in your shell's rc file:

`alias nonode="export NODE_REPL_HISTORY="/dev/null" && node && unset NODE_REPL_HISTORY"`